# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure: Where clause with number-named column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table with some columns named as number

```
Table1 (id, 2014, 2015, 2016)
```

When I am trying to access these columns in a `where` clause in a stored procedure, I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near '.2014'.

Here is the code of the stored procedure:

```
select @SiteNumOfItems = COUNT(*)    
from form.ItemStore I
where I.id = @id and I.2014 = 'Item1'
```

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add `[]`

For example :

```
select @SiteNumOfItems=COUNT(*) from form.ItemStore I
    where I.id = @id and I.[2014] = 'Item1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select @SiteNumOfItems=COUNT(*) from form.ItemStore I
    where I.id = @id and I.[2014] = 'Item1'
```